React Native did not auto refresh
I'm currently developing a React Native mobile app using Expo Go, and I initially had no issues with auto-refresh in the emulator. Whenever I saved changes, the emulator would automatically refresh, which was really helpful during development.
However, after publishing my app to the Apple App Store and Google Play Store, Apple recommended that I add a "Delete Account" feature before they could approve it. I added this feature and went back to test it, but now, the emulator no longer auto-refreshes when I save my changes.
Here are the things I've tried so far:

Disabling and re-enabling auto-refresh: I turned off auto-refresh in the Expo Go settings and then re-enabled it, but the problem persists.

Checking and modifying the app.json file: I reviewed the app.json file for any potential misconfigurations, but nothing seems out of place.

Switching modes: I noticed that there are two modes in Expo Go—Development Mode and Production Mode. I've tried switching between these modes, but it hasn't resolved the issue.


I'm unsure what else I can do to make the emulator auto-refresh again. Is there something I might be missing or a specific setting that needs to be adjusted?
I cannot present the code to run because there are lots of files that need to consider. Maybe I will post here my app.json file
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Investor Wallet",
    "slug": "investor-wallet",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/logo.png",
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "App ID"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/logo.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
      "package": "App ID"
    },
    "web": {
      "bundler": "metro",
      "output": "static",
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "expo-router"
    ],
    "experiments": {
      "typedRoutes": true
    },
    "extra": {
      "router": {
        "origin": false
      },
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "my project id"
      }
    },
    "owner": "amurobrian18",
    "runtimeVersion": {
      "policy": "appVersion"
    },
    "updates": {
      "url": "update link"
    }
  }
}

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Did you kill metro and restart and rebuild?

Yes I killed metro and restart and rebuild. The issue still there
